# How to get data from angular expressions {{}} in to script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-xeditable

I am using angular xeditable text and I am trying to edit a text in a table row. whenever I click on a text it creates a textbox properly but it does not put the data in which should be edited. I do not know how to assign that text to the $scope object.

please help!

Here is my HTML table code

```
 <tbody>

                {% for user in User %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ user.uid }} </td>
                    <td><a href="#" editable-text="user.taskname"> {{ user.taskname }} </a>

                        <span style="padding-right:3px; padding-top: 3px; display:inline-block;" ></span>
                        <input type="image" class="deleteImg"
                               src="static/img/trash_can.png" height="15px"
                               width="18px" name="removeId"
                               value={{user.uid}} ></input> 
                        <input type="image" src="static/img/editbtn.svg"
                               height="15px" width="18px" name="editId"
                               value={{user.uid}} ></input> 

                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my Script

```
  <script>
     var newItem ={};
    var app = angular.module("app", ['xeditable']);
    app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myname="Howdy";
    $scope.user={
         taskname: 'Here goes the main logic'
    };

    });
    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//').endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.run(function(editableOptions) {
        editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Anything in the console? Check out their [user guide](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) for setup...

Comment: Can u create a jsfiddle :)?

Comment: @AndyHe Here is my Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/pd0uaOakYNtfvxDSysha?p=preview

Comment: @WilliamHampshire there is nothing on console

Comment: @Prasanna I had no problems seeing content in the textbox when going to edit mode (in the Plunker). When not being in edit mode the content was `{{ user.taskname }}` though. I removed the code related to `$interpolateProvider` to fix it.